# “Decorate” several types with same static member function and attribute

Tags: f#

I have a list of discriminated unions types e.g.

```
type Name = Name of string | NoName
type Coordinate = Coordinate of float * float | NoCoordinate
…
```

and all need the same static member function and the same attribute. E.g.

```
[<KnownType("GetKnownTypes")>]
type Name = Name of string | NoName with
    static member GetKnownTypes() =
            typedefof<Name>.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic) 
            |> Array.filter FSharpType.IsUnion
```

How can I “decorate” every type of that list without having to add the static member GetKnownTypes() to every single type, in order to avoid code duplicates. Maybe a solution with interfaces or inheritance.

Basically I need this code in better programming style:

```
[<KnownType("GetKnownTypes")>]
type Name = Name of string | NoName with
    static member GetKnownTypes() =
            typedefof<Name>.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic) 
            |> Array.filter FSharpType.IsUnion

[<KnownType("GetKnownTypes")>]
type Coordinate = Coordinate of float * float | NoCoordinate with
    static member GetKnownTypes() =
            typedefof<Coordinate>.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic) 
            |> Array.filter FSharpType.IsUnion
```

Thanks

Comment: First code snippet makes me think that you're missing `Option<>` type functionality

Comment: Also, I wonder if you need to constrain `GetKnownTypes` for these 2 types only. Because it looks like it simply can be made generic.

Comment: I need `GetKnownTypes` in more than 2 types. How can I make it generic?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it may be overkill, but do you mean this sort of thing?

```ml
type IReflective = 
    abstract GetKnownTypes : unit -> Type[]

let getKnownTypes<'T>() = 
    typedefof<'T>.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic) 
    |> Array.filter FSharpType.IsUnion

type Name = 
    Name of string | NoName
    interface IReflective with
        member __.GetKnownTypes() = getKnownTypes<Name>()

type Coordinate = 
    Coordinate of float * float | NoCoordinate
    interface IReflective with
        member __.GetKnownTypes() = getKnownTypes<Coordinate>()
```

I've left out the `attribute` bit of the question as I'm not sure I understand the objective there.

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner.